# CORS preflight request returning HTTP 401 with windows authentication

Tags: iis, cors, windows-authentication, preflight

I searched a lot on Google and Stack overflow to find a solution for my problem, but nothing worked.

Here is my problem:

- I use IIS 7 with a special programming environment called WebDEV that does not allow direct manipulation of `OPTIONS` HTTP method. So, all solutions suggesting some kind of server-side request handling using code are not feasible.
- I have to use Window authentication and disable anonymous access
- I have a page that uses CORS to POST to this server. As this POST should have `Content-type: Octet-stream`, a preflight is issued by the browser.
- When I enable anonymous access, everything works fine (CORS is well configured)
- When I disable anonymous access, the server replies with HTTP 401 unauthorized response to the preflight request, as it does not contain credentials information.
- I tried to write a module for IIS that accepts OPTIONS requests like this, but it did not work (couldn't add the module correctly to IIS, maybe)

  ```
  public class CORSModule : IHttpModule
     {

            public void Dispose() { 
            }

            public void Init(HttpApplication context)
            {
                 context.PreSendRequestHeaders += delegate
                 {
                    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
                     {
                           var response = context.Response;
                           response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                     }
                 };
            }
      }
  ```

The question is: How can I make IIS respond with HTTP 200 to the preflight request without enabling anonymous access or writing some server-side code? Is there an easy configuration or a ready-made module for IIS to do so? At least, what are the detailed steps to install the above module into IIS 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution that uses "URL Rewrite" IIS module. It works perfectly.

1- Stop IIS service (maybe not necessary)

2- Install "web platform installer" from https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

3- Go to "Applications" tab and search for "URL Rewrite" and download it

4- Install this hotfix KB2749660 (maybe not necessary)

5- Open IIS configuration tool, double click "URL Rewrite"

6- Add a new blankrule

7- Give it any name

8- In "Match URL", specify this pattern: `.*`

9- In "Conditions", specify this condition entry: `{REQUEST_METHOD}` and this pattern: `^OPTIONS$`

10- In "Action", specify: action type `Personalized response`, state code `200`, reason `Preflight`, description `Preflight`

11- Start the server

Now, the server should reply with a 200 status code response to the preflight request, regardless of the authentication.

Remarks: I also disabled all compression, I don't know if it matters.

Comment: life saver bro +1

Comment: Later Microsoft shipped official CORS module for IIS, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference so this workaround is no longer needed.

Comment: @LexLi Well, great!

Comment: Has anyone actually managed to get the CORS Module to work? I've read 100 different articles but absolutely nothing works. It seems totally impossible to do a very basic AJAX request if you have Windows Authentication enabled. It's utterly ridiculous!

Comment: @ChrisGilbert This is why I am still using the URL Rewrite module :)

Answer (score 9):

From AhmadWabbi's answer, easy XML pasting into your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CORS Preflight Anonymous Authentication" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^OPTIONS$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="200" statusReason="Preflight" statusDescription="Preflight" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your module to take precedence it will have to override any modules within IIS that may interfere. For instance, your web.config may need a  or enable anonymous, and create an attribute for intercepting the traffic and filtering through as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers that involve writing code, using the rewrite module, or hard-coding values in `web.config` were correct when they were written, but I believe the correct answer to this problem in 2020 is to use the [official IIS CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module).  This will handle all the little gotchas like having to allow unauthenticated OPTIONS requests, without otherwise supporting unauthenticated users.

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361880/215140) has some really great details about using this module, but the simplest configuration is right at the top:

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*" allowCredentials="true" />
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
```

I would certainly change the `origin="*"` to the specific origin you expect to use the API from.  You can have more than one `<add>` tag, and the linked answer shows how to customize allowed headers, methods, etc. for each.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, this following article is worth a read.  There are two solutions presented - one using Authorization rules, and another using the IIS Cors module.  I had the exact same problem described in this thread and both solutions worked well for me.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/putting-it-all-together-cors-tutorial/ba-p/775331

My web.config for the API website had the following for the cors config:

```
<cors enabled="true" failUnlistedOrigins="true">
    <add origin="http://clienthost:clientport" allowCredentials="true">
      <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true" />
      <allowMethods>
        <add method="GET" />
        <add method="HEAD" />
        <add method="POST" />
        <add method="PUT" /> 
        <add method="DELETE" />   
      </allowMethods>
    </add>      
  </cors>
```

I had Anonymous Authenication disabled when using the Cors module solution.