# IIS and jQuery CORS - 401 returned on preflight

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, cors

**Overview:**

I have access to both the server (IIS) and the code (jQuery, MVC project, etc). We needed to set up CORS in order for the front-end devs to hit the APIs on our QA server. The IIS server has "Basic Authentication" enabled, and has the following "**Access-Control-Allow-XX**" enabled:

- `Credentials : true`
- `Headers : Content-Type, Authorization`
- `Methods : GET,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD`
- `Origin : http://myLocal`
  `// I did have`*`as this, but
  the response was complaining that I could not have a wildcard -- did
  not understand this`

**jQuery  (U/P omitted)**

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://ourQAserver.com' + fcs_vars.subscribeURL,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('USERNAME:PASS')
            //,'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        //beforesend: function (xhr) {
        //    xhr.setrequestheader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('USERNAME:PASS'));
        //},
        //crossdomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: user,
        cache: false,
        ....
        ....
```

As you can see above, I've tried different ways to get this to work. The current error I'm receiving from the request is:

> Failed to load
>   https://ourQAserver.com/area/controller/action:
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

There is no "Response" from the server (in Chrome dev tools)

One thought was that I had to enable CORS in MVC, using the Nuget pkg, and then adding the attribute onto the controller, but I did not do this since I have access to IIS itself.

Comment: I think it may not be the CORS, but the authentication. Could you try to access a controller without `[Authorize]` attribute  ?

Comment: Before I added the `Authorization` header attribute (this is not a MVC attribute, but for sending encoded base64 string as username/pass), I was receiving a different error in Google's console, relating to the fact that I wasn't (at the time) sending the creds. I cannot take the "Basic Auth" off of the IIS app pool unfortunately, as our QA environment shouldn't be accessed from outside the network.

Comment: You need to configure your server backend to not require authorization for `OPTIONS` requests to `https://ourqaserver.com/area/controller/action`. The 401 status code in the message cited in the question indicates the server is requiring authorization for an `OPTIONS` request, but authorization is failing because the request doesn’t contain the required credentials. The reason is, that `OPTIONS` request is sent automatically by your browser as part of CORS, and the browser doesn’t add the `Authorization` header to that preflight `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: In more detail: 1. Your code tells your browser it wants to send a request with the Authorization header. 2. Browser says, OK, requests with the Authorization header require me to do a CORS preflight OPTIONS to make sure the server allows requests with the Authorization header. 3. Browser sends the OPTIONS to the server *without the `Authorization` header*. 4.  Server sees the OPTIONS but rejects it with a 401 since it lacks the header. 5. Browser expects 200 response for the preflight but instead gets 401. So browser stops right there and never tries the POST request from your code.

Comment: So you must figure out what part of your current server-side code causes your server to require authorization for OPTIONS, and change that so it instead handles OPTIONS without authorization being required. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains in general why browsers make CORS preflight OPTIONS requests, and what headers the response must contain; specifically, the response to the preflight OPTIONS in this case must have the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization' response headers.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Apprec the thorough comments, I'll definitely take a look at these suggestions first thing in the morning (laptop is at work). I don't want you to think that your time is not appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an OPTIONS endpoint. 
The client will first make an OPTIONS request and if that succeeds, issues GET or POST calls.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// OPTIONS method that is used by client browser to make a handshake
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>bool object</returns>
    [HttpOptions]
    public bool Options()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @sideshowbarker for the assistance, pointed me on the correct path

Added these (4) `customHeaders` in IIS. Apparently you have to specify a value (instead of using the wildcard *) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when the IIS server is expecting credentials. Also, there is no wildcard for `Headers`, hence the large amount needed.

We had the requirement to have multiple `Origins` listed, and since the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is very strict (in the since that there can be only one fully declared URL), I found this nifty rewrite to get around that issue.

[Access-control-allow-origin with multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains)

Here's a list of all Headers that are possible

[Cors Access-Control-Allow-Headers wildcard being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146892/cors-access-control-allow-headers-wildcard-being-ignored)

Here is the post regarding redirecting `OPTIONS` request via IIS Rewrite

[CORS preflight request returning HTTP 401 with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201776/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-401-with-windows-authentication?rq=1)

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="CORS Preflight Anonymous Authentication" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^OPTIONS$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="200" statusReason="Preflight" statusDescription="Preflight" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <!-- Added for CORS -->
    <rule name="AddCrossDomainHeader">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern="(http(s)?://((.+\.)?domain1\.com|(.+\.)?domain2\.com|(.+\.)?domain3\.com))" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

---

You don't need to specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` here b/c we're using it in the rewrite

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Allow, Authorization,Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Cookie, GET, HEAD, Keep-Alive, OPTIONS, Origin, POST, Pragma, Referer, Refresh, Status, User-Agent " />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
```

---

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://qa.URL.com' + fcs_vars.subscribeURL,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('myUser:myPass')
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        crossdomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: user,
        complete: function (response) {
            if (response.readyState == 4) { 
                // code here
```