# How to authorize CORS preflight request on IIS with Windows Authentication

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, cors, windows-authentication, preflight

I have an API on ASP.net Core 2 (windows authentication) and a front on angular. 
I make a cors configuration to querying my backend from the SPA angular, but im blocked in cause of the preflight who are rejected from the IIS server because he don't have identification information.

error message :

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://XXXXXX' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

code side front :

```
//MY HEADER
private headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':'true',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'true'
});

//REQUEST
let options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers, withCredentials:true});
return this.http.get(this.tasksUrl,options).map(res=>res.json());
```

code side back : (Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddCors();
   services.AddCors(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder =>
            {
               builder.WithOrigins("http://theURLofTheFront:8080" )
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
            });
   });
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

I try this :

[CORS preflight request returning HTTP 401 with windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201776/cors-preflight-request-returning-http-401-with-windows-authentication).

and i added custom header to specify the 'Acces-control-allow-origin' on IIS, dont work for me.

and this dont work for me : 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/11/24/putting-it-all-together-cors-tutorial/

I can't remove the default authorization rule.

I thank you in advance for you

Comment: I solved my problem with the IIS module CORS

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to accomplish this, other answers can be found on this similar question --> [Angular4 ASP.NET Core 1.2 Windows Authentication CORS for PUT and POST Gives 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108307/)

---

## CORS Module

It is possible to configure IIS by using the [CORS Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module).
As seen here:  https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module
And further information available here: https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

> The IIS CORS module is designed to handle the CORS preflight requests
> before other IIS modules handle the same request. The OPTIONS requests
> are always anonymous, so CORS module provides IIS servers a way to
> correctly respond to the preflight request even if anonymous
> authentification needs to be disabled server-wise.

You will need to enable the CORS Module via the Webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="*" allowCredentials="true" />
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

for more granular control:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="https://readonlyservice.constoso.com" allowCredentials="true">
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
        </allowMethods>
        <allowHeaders>
            <add header="content-type" /> 
            <add header="accept" /> 
        </allowHeaders>
      </add>
      <add origin="https://readwriteservice.constoso.com" allowCredentials="true">
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" /> 
            <add method="DELETE" />         
        </allowMethods>
      </add>
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

## Redirect OPTIONS

You can redirect all OPTIONS requests to always give an OK status.
This will however subvert the entire idea of a preflight request, so use this only if it's applicable to your situation.

Install the [redirect module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/#setup) in IIS.
Add the following redirect to your Webconfig.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="CORS Preflight Anonymous Authentication" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^OPTIONS$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="200" statusReason="Preflight" statusDescription="Preflight" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

---

## Middleware

Alternatively the desired result can be achieved by enabling anonymous authentication in IIS and creating a middleware in the Net Core API that checks if a person is properly authenticated.

Middleware:

```
public AuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger logger)
{
    _next = next;
    _log = logger;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    //Allow OPTIONS requests to be anonymous
    if (httpContext.Request.Method != "OPTIONS" && !httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Not Authenticated");
    }
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

Comment: cannot seem to install the IIS module CORS on my ancient IIS 6.1 (Win 2008 R2) server - which is probably to be expected. The Web Platform Installer doesn't like the download

Comment: strike my prior comment, I did get it installed on my Win2008 R2 after all, [from further down on the same page there was an x64 link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=862444)

Comment: That rewrite rule CORS Preflight Anonymous Authentication was all I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Preflight request does not send authentication information.  So, enable anonymous authentication as well (no need to remove windows authentication).  refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354772/946773

Comment: Enabling anonymous authentication without additional changes will just allow anybody to access resources which is most likely not the goal.