# How to configure CORS on Azure App Service

Tags: windows, azure-web-app-service

PREFACE: I know how this is done in the general sense, my question is how to best set it up on Azure App Service

a) Where is configuration done for CORS on a Rest Service (App-#1) hosted on Azure App Service? Is it the traditional way via C# code e.g. config.EnableCors(); or can it also be done via Azure Portal magic?

b) If the client App (App-#2) is hosted on (another) Azure App Service, where to find the external IP address which will be sent in Ajax calls to App-#1?

Comment: App Service (Windows) or (Linux)?

Comment: @Lex Li Windows (but is it different with Linux ? You could answer for that as well)

Comment: App Service on Windows is almost IIS/Windows, so existing discussions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450854/how-to-authorize-cors-preflight-request-on-iis-with-windows-authentication covered that. App Service on Linux is a completely different story.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it the traditional way via C# code e.g. config.EnableCors(); or can it also be done via Azure Portal magic?

Thanks @Lex Li for the comment.

We can configure CORS either from [`code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or from `Azure Portal` => Deployed `App Service`.

To enable `CORS` in `Azure App Service`,
Navigate to the deployed `App Service` in `Azure Portal` => select  `CORS` UNDER `API`.

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#enable-cors) we can also enable `CORS` using Azure CLI.

***My Initial `CORS` section:***

[image]

Run the below command in `Azure Cloud Shell`.

```cs
az webapp cors add --resource-group YourResourceGroup --name YourAppServiceName --allowed-origins 'URL of the Application or * '
```

[image]

Now, check the `CORS` section under `API`.

You can see the Allowed `Origins` is added.

[image]

- If you set `CORS` policy in both `Code` and in `Azure Portal`, then the setting of code will be overridden with the settings in Portal.

> If the client App (App-#2) is hosted on (another) Azure App Service, where to find the external IP address which will be sent in Ajax calls to App-#1?

- In this case we can use the `hostname` directly instead of `IP Address` like [below](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api.md#browse-to-the-azure-app)

> ```cs
> https://AppServiceName.azurewebsites.net/api/<controller>/<action
> ```

As mentioned in the [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips.md) use the below command to find the `possibleOutboundIpAddresses` .

[image]