CORS thinks Access-Control-Allow-Origin value is wildcard, but it's not
I am trying to create a login system for my company's site, and send a refresh token as a cookie after a successful login. After scouring the internet and SO for similar issues, I have a solution that works in localhost, but I can't get it to work in production. This is the error I'm getting in production:
Access to fetch at 'https://my-linux-api.azurewebsites.net/my-site/login' from origin 'https://www.my-site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

This is really doing my head in, because the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is definitely not "*". Here is my route in my Node JS api:
router.post("/my-site/login", function(req, res) {    
    var email = req.body.Email;
    var password = req.body.Password;
    var connection = new Connection(config);    

    var query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE Email = @email"
    const request = new Request(query,         
        function(err) {            
            connection.close();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send([]);
            }  
        }
    );
    
    request.addParameter('email', TYPES.VarChar, email);

    var result = [];
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else
        {            
            request.on('row', function(columns) {                     
                var col = [] 
                columns.forEach((column) => {                      
                    col.push(column.value);
                });                
                result.push(col);                                
            });

            request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount) {                
                if (result.length > 0) {        
                    
                    if (result[0][4] == password) {
                        if (result[0][8] !== 0) {
                            result[0].splice(4, 1);                            
                            const accessPayload = ({ User: result[0], Type: "Authentication" })
                            const accessToken = jwt.sign(accessPayload, process.env.secretKey, { expiresIn: 86400 });

                            const refreshPayload = ({ User: result[0][0], Type: "Refresh" })
                            const refreshToken = jwt.sign(refreshPayload, process.env.secretKey, { expiresIn: 172800 });
                            
                            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "https://www.my-site.com");
                            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
                            res.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);    
                            res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
                                httpOnly: true,
                                secure: true,
                                sameSite: 'Lax',
                                path: "/"                                
                            })                        
                            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            res.json({ success: true, message: "Authorization Successful" });                           
                        }
                        else {                            
                            res.sendStatus(403)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        res.sendStatus(401);
                    }

                }
                else {
                    res.sendStatus(401)
                }
            })

            request.on('requestCompleted', (rowCount, more)=> {                    
                connection.close();
            })

            connection.execSql(request);  
        }
    })
});

As you can see, I've set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the name of my site. I have checked and double checked to make sure there are no trailing slashes.
Also, instead of setting the headers within the route, I have tried using the cors package, and using it as one of the parameters for my route, as per the documentation:
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'https://www.my-site.com',
    credentials: true,
};

router.post("/my-site/login", cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) { ....

I've seen some people say that errors like this are red herrings, and the actual problem is elsewhere, but the fact that this works locally when I set the header to "http://localhost:3000" leads me to believe that there are no other issues.
Here is the frontend code, for posterity:
export const Login = (email: string, password: string, context: any) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('Email', email);
    formData.append('Password', password);

    await fetch(url + "my-site/login", {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: formData
    })
    .then((res: any) => {       
      let rawToken = res.headers.get("authorization").split(" ")[1];      
      var accessToken = jwt.decode(rawToken);     
      context.setUser(accessToken.User);
      context.setIsAuthenticated(true);
      localStorage.setItem(
        "authorization",
        rawToken
      )
      if (localStorage.getItem("theme") == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
      }

      resolve("Success")
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.response.status == 403) {
        reject(403);
      } else if (err.response.status == 401) {
        reject(401);
      } else {
        reject("Error, please try again later");
      }
    })
  });

I don't understand how it can be convention to store refresh tokens as cookies if CORS makes it so difficult to do so.
Thank you in advance

You made a post to /my-site/login, but cors is configured for the route /solutions/login, is this correct?
And also, if you want to implement cors, add it as middleware for every route, something like this:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://www.example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


My apologies, 'solutions' is a shorthand name for our site, I forgot to anonymize that part. And yes, I made a post request to "/my-site/login", but I have the cors origin property set to the base url for my site, i.e. the url it says it's rejecting requests from in the error message. Also, I did try what you've suggested, only to get the same error.

Hi, CORS will work in localhost as per the given configuration. However when it goes to a productive environment, it greatly depends upon the kind of CORS configurable methods the specific hosting partner provides. It also varies from partner to partner. I have been trying a lot with Vercel, still to find the success.  Request it would be needing to follow and try  the specific CORS settings methods azurewebsites.net provides. Please see this post if useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75702313/how-to-configure-cors-on-azure-app-service

@WeDoTheBest4You If you say that CORS behavior also depends on the hosting platform, then I believe that's my issue. I'm also using Vercel, to no avail obviously. Thank you for the insight.

Hi, Thank you for your response. Please see the post here https://vercel.community/t/cors-issue/442/2 I have been asking for assistance with them. The good thing I found with Vercel is that it does not put cap on the free accounts, it gives better speed compared to a few other hosting providers especially Render.

...This is the site wherein Vercel team provides direct support - https://vercel.community , kindly be noted and try it out if it is something specific to Vercel.
